# How to put an image in the header of drawer in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am using React Navigation Version: 5.x. Here is my App.js:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import ImageInDrawer from './common/ImageInDrawer';

const DrawerAccountant = createDrawerNavigator();

function AccountantDrawer() {
  return (
    <DrawerAccountant.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" contentComponent={ImageInDrawer}>
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="Home" component={AccountantScreen} />
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="My Account" component={MyAccountScreen} />
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="Tasks" component={TasksScreen} />
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="Task Price" component={TaskPriceScreen} />
    </DrawerAccountant.Navigator>
  );
}
```

This is the code of ImageInDrawer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class ImageInDrawer extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/man.jpg')}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I tried this code but I am not able to display any image in the drawer. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried providing width and height for the image

Comment: Yes, I tired. But nothing

Answer (score 0):

here is the link and try this example
https://aboutreact.com/custom-navigation-drawer-sidebar-with-image-and-icon-in-menu-options/
[image]

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawer-cover.png')} style={{flex: 1, width: 280, justifyContent: 'center'}} >
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Header Portion</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>You can display here logo or profile image</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
```

Add your image path and try it.

Comment: They have made a separate file to place the code of Drawer. Whereas I have placed my code in App.js. They are using react-navigation-drawer whereas I am using @react-navigation/drawer.

Comment: I am not able to do it as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using drawerContent instead of contentComponent.